# Need help understanding the following two hints at the proof of: If $f$ and $\overline{f}$ are holomorphic then $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that $f$ must be constant by directly checking via the CR equations. But I'm having trouble understanding the following two hints at the proof for the same problem. Will someone please explain how they produce a proof that $f$ is constant?

> Hint 1: Let $g(z):=f(z)\overline{f(z)}.$ Then $g(z)=|f(z)|^2$ is
> analytic and real(!). Conclusion?
>
> Reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3508467/544059

> Hint 2: Note that if $f$  and $\overline{f}$ are analytic, then
> $\mathrm{Re} f$ and $\mathrm{Im} f$ are analytic. But these take only
> real values.
>
> Reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1078002/544059

Comment: They seem to intend to use the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)). Since no non-empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open in $\mathbb{C}$, then the analytic functions taking only real values must be constant. The second hint immediately gives $f$, constant, since its real and imaginary parts are constant.

Comment: Hint 1 could be finished by another application of the open mapping theorem, since $f$ is analytic an the hint (with the OMT) has proven that its values are on a circle, no non-empty subset of which is open in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The open mapping theorem is straightforward and very powerful. The CR equations are fine but they obscure the essence of the proof.